# XFS File System Lack of Space

Tags: linux, disk-usage, xfs

I am using a xfs file system at work for storing image processing data. Currently, it has around 8.8T of free space.

```
/dev/sdh1             106T   97T  8.8T  92%
```

While there are plans to move some of the data to tape and make room, it won't happen until next week. Currently, I keep running into "No space left on device" error quite regularly.

Usually the images trasferred are around 128mb in size and they are around 100-500 of them at time.

Is there anything specific to the file system that is making these ~8TB of free space unusable?

On my end, I was able to verify that I can use atleast 8TB of this space using the command `fallocate` to create really large files of around a TB.

What I am missing? Are there any obvious file-system level checks that I need to do?

For your reference, here is the output of the command `xfs_info` for the filesystem.

```
meta-data=/dev/sdh1              isize=256    agcount=106, agsize=268435455 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=28319810304, imaxpct=1
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=521728, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

In order to reproduce the same error, I wrote a simple shell script that creates a large number of files(10k) small files (1M in size) and it fails with the following error:

```
fallocate: temfile-7464: open failed: No space left on device
```

Here is the output of `df -i` before the script is run

```
/dev/sdh1             4531169600  648793  4530520807    1% /jumbo/K2LEGINON
```

And after

```
/dev/sdh1             4531169600  656256  4530513344    1% /jumbo/K2LEGINON
```

It failed after creating around ~7500 files. Which amount to  ~ 7.3G.

Comment: What is giving you the lack of space errors?  A `mv` command in Bash?  A web front-end to the image processing application?

Comment: The images are usually trasferred from another local computer where the the parition is used via nfs/samba.

Comment: What does `df -i` show?

Comment: I update the question with that information

Comment: In that case, we'd need to see before and after `df` along with the command used, the size of the affected files and the exact error message.

Comment: Sure thing. Updated accordingly.

Comment: This is often a problem on 32-bit inode file systems  http://serverfault.com/questions/696064/unable-to-create-files-on-large-xfs-filesystem

Comment: Thanks! I suspected it was something specific to the XFS filesystem. I guess I owe you a beer Mark :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to responses in the comments, I was able to identify the problem as XFS filesystem related.

Essentially, the filesystem was running out free space for creating inodes. The XFS filesystem seems to be using the first one Terabyte of the disk to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> In the case of a filesystem already running inode64, this error can be encountered if the filesystem does run low/out of disk space -- or if it cannot allocate 4 contiguous blocks for additional inodes.  So if the filesystem is severely fragmented -- meaning only 1-3 blocks are together -- you will not be able to create new files but can write additional data to older files.

> For further information on identifying how fragmented the free space is, please see TID 7014320 - How to tell how fragmented the free space on an XFS filesystem

> If your filesystem is severely fragmented, you can either:
> add a significant amount of free space (i.e. 20% or more)
> move the data to a different filesystem and then copy it back.
> this will remove the free blocks between files and make it contiguous.  You will find this most helpful for filesystems that store files that are <= 4,096 bytes.

https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7014318